# why does mathjax go throught the same processing on same visited page each time?

Tags: mathjax

I have a page with mathml to be processed by mathjax. I noticed each time I visit the page (not just the first time) I see the same processing:

```
  ...waiting for cdf.mathjax.org
  ...processing math... 
  ...typesetting math 5% 10% 20%....
```

I would have expected that once the page is loaded first time, then next time it is visited, it will come up instantly since it is in the browser cache now. But I guess my understanding was wrong.

The header of the page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head><title>integrals 51 - 100</title> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="report.css" /> 
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({ extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], jax: 
["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"], tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ], 
displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ], processEscapes: true }, 
"HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] } }); </script> <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> 
</script><style type="text/css"> .MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;} 
</style></head>
<body>
```

My question is: Is this how it is supposed to work? I am not forcing the page to reload by something like holding the SHIFT key and reloading the page. I simply visit the page, hit the browser back key, then click on the link again to visit the page again.

I tried this on firefox 34.0.05 and Chrom. I am on windows 7.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well mathjax formatted equations are generated by javascript. Each time a page is reloaded the javascript is rerun. To prevent this javascript being run each time you would need some sort of cached solution requiring complex code in the backend. There are problems with caching the results as not all browser are the same, the font size may be different and the actual window sizes can vary. All these can impact on the precise details of the equations generated.

People have been working on a cached mathjax solution on wikipedia but the results are still inferior to those generated on the fly.

Comment: I have thought it will be fast the second time, like with pages that contain images. First time the page is loaded it will be slow, but as long as one does not force reloading the page, next time it is clicked on to visit, it shows up right away since it is in the browser cache. If Matjax has to do its processing each time like this, then it will not work for me really. Thanks for the confirmation.